# Arrayformula get value of cell above if condition meets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need to get the value of the cell above if a condition is met in an arrayformula as I need it to expand automatically when a new row is added

In excel I would use a table with a function looking something like:

In B2: `=IF(A2="",A1,A2)`

In google sheets I do not know how to achieve this:

In B2: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Row(A:A)="","",ROW(A:A)-1))`

I thought that `ROW(A:A)-1` would subtract 1 from the current row number and give me the result. But that did not work.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Can you share a copy of the sheet?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A1000="", A1:A999, A2:A1000))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @player0 . Unfortunatelly this does not work for me :(. It only works one time (if there is only one empty cell), but if I have 2 or more, it does not workk anymore.